# Laravel : How to update boolean value using foreign key in a table

Tags: database, laravel, foreign-keys, boolean, updates

[image]

here is my database table I want to work with I want to update the participation column of form_submissions table with boolean 1 by using the user_id

here is mycontroller

```
 public function update($id)
    {
        $submission = Form_Submission::find($id);
        $submission->participation=1;
        $submission->save();
        return back();
    {
```

I got the user_id from the link using a button and passed it to the function
can someone tell me how I can update the above record using user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `user_id`, you can retrieve that specific `Form_Submission` using `where`, like this:

```php
Form_Submission::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

Resource for this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Also, to update it, you can use where - update, like this:

```php
Form_Submission::where('user_id', $user_id)->update(['participation' => 1]);
```

Resource for this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#updates

Hope this helps!